# PySpark - create map from counts of values in dataframe column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have this kind of dataframe and I need to create output dataframe that will have this column but its value will be a map of the values and theirs count:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('new',), ('new',), ('old',)],
    ["x"]
)
```

I have tried multiple things, the closest was this which gives me 2 rows, but I need it in one row:

```
agg = df.groupBy("x").agg(F.count("*").alias("count"))
agg.select(F.create_map(agg["x"], agg["count"]).alias("counts")).show()
```

But I want to create output like this, so basically it's schema will be MapType(StringType(),IntegerType()),True):

```
+--------------------+
|              counts|
+--------------------+
|{new -> 2, old -> 1}|
+--------------------+
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Code

```
(
    df
    .groupBy('x')
    .agg(F.expr("struct(x, count(x)) as counts"))
    .agg(F.expr('map_from_entries(collect_list(counts)) as counts'))
)
```

#### Result

```
+--------------------+
|              counts|
+--------------------+
|{new -> 2, old -> 1}|
+--------------------+
```

#### Details

- Group the dataframe and aggregate to create a struct of group key and corresponding count for e.g. `{new, 2}`
- Aggregate the dataframe again and collect all such structs in a list and use [`map_from_entries`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_entries.html) to create a map from list of structs

Comment: Figured something similar by myself, but thanks

df.groupby("x").count().agg(
    F.map_from_entries(
      F.collect_list(
        F.when(F.col("x").isNotNull(),F.struct("x","count"))
      )
    ).alias("map")).show(4,False)

Answer (score 1):

you can create a map column after the pivoting the aggregation.

```py
agg_sdf = data_sdf. \
    groupBy(func.lit(1).alias('dummy')). \
    pivot("x"). \
    agg(func.count("*").alias("count"))

agg_sdf. \
    select(func.create_map(*reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [(func.lit(c), func.col(c)) for c in agg_sdf.drop('dummy').columns])).alias('counts')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +--------------------+
# |counts              |
# +--------------------+
# |{new -> 2, old -> 1}|
# +--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I am late but here is another version using `create_map`

`create_map` requires `key1,val1,key2,val2,ley3,val3...` to create the map and we use list comprehension to generate the list

```
%python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([('new',), ('new',), ('old',)],["x"])
agg_df = df.groupBy("x").agg(F.count("*").alias("count"))

map_col = F.create_map([F.lit(column) for row in agg_df.collect() for column in row])
agg_df.select('x','count',map_col).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+--------------------+
|  x|count| map(new, 2, old, 1)|
+---+-----+--------------------+
|new|    2|{new -> 2, old -> 1}|
|old|    1|{new -> 2, old -> 1}|
+---+-----+--------------------+
```